# How to get apt package cache directory location?

Tags: apt, deb

How to get/know where is `apt` package's cache directory location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with this command for cache directory location:
`apt-config shell Cache Dir::Cache`
And this command for cache/archive directory location:
`apt-config shell Cache Dir::Cache::Archives`

Answer (score 9):

The complete location can be obtained as follows:

```
eval $(apt-config shell CACHE Dir::Cache)
eval $(apt-config shell ARCHIVES Dir::Cache::archives)
echo /${CACHE}/${ARCHIVES}
```

(`apt-config shell` is designed to be used in this way).

The first command gives the base directory for all the caches, the second gives the path to the archives, starting from the base directory.